# how to add the value of one column to the existing value of another column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

if i have a new comment in "new comment" column, i want that comment to be added to the existing comments in "comment summary" column but should be in a format of line break. How can I do this in Sharepoint Designer 2013?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you could do this.

You could solve this without workflow by turning versioning on your list and adding a multiple lines of text field with the appending setting turned on.  This will time stamp the comment along with marking who made it.  That is completely out of the box and works nicely, but may not fit your use case.

Another way to do this would be through a SPD workflow.  The pseudo code would look something like this:

```
If 'New Comment' is not empty
  Set 'Comments Summary' to '[%Current Item:Comments Summary%]' + '[%Current Item:New Comment%]' //Format however you wish in the String Builder
  then Set 'New Comment' to blankString //Create local variable named blankString and don't give it a value
```

EDIT:

The first option's functionality doesn't work in quick edit and is also not able to be viewed in a regular list view (You will see 'More entries..' or something similar).  You can get around the viewing part by using a data view web part, but if you need to be able to quick edit then you will want to go with the workflow and second approach.

Comment: thank you jordan! i tried the first option and it worked, however, i cannot input a new comment if i am using the quick edit view. How can I enable inputting new comment via the quick edit?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank jordan! I tried the 2nd option and its not working. Basically, I have 3 columns: 1st - for new comment, 2nd - will contain the new comment and modified details which is automatic, 3rd - is when I want to add the 2nd column to the existing details of 3rd column.

My string is:
If New Comment is not empty
   Set Comment Display to [New Comment],[Modified Date],[Modified by]
   then set New Comment to blankstring

If Comment Display is not empty
   Set Comment Summary to [Comment Summary] + [Comment Display]

Am I missing something?